# which will the best way to use the result of function between assigning it to a variable or calling the function again and again?

Tags: c++, variables, c++11

I have a function which will return a value, i want to use the result of the function in multiple places. Storing the result to a variable and use it where ever i want or directly call the function again and again instead of storing it in a variable and using that.

```
#include<iostream>

int function(int x,int y){
  return (x<<y);
}

int main(){
  int a = 10;
  int b = 5;
  int c = function(a,b);
  int d = c*c; 
  int e =function(a,b)*function(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you compared measurements of the two versions, what did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirety on your function and your code. If your function is

```
struct DeepThought {
    int theAnswer() {
        sleep(7.5 million years);
        return 42;
    }
};
```

then I would want to cache the answer somewhere so as not to pay that penalty more than once. However, if your function is faster than your minimum bar for performance, your code might be more readable with the function than it would be without. Of course, if the function in question isn't pure, this question is moot. See also memoization.